# Google Sheet script reset drop down boxes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a tab for each day of the week.  On each tab there are several dropdown boxes that I would like to reset at the beginning of the week to either "Select" or "0".  The cells effected are the exact same on each tab.  I have identified the cells that need to be reset to "Select" and the cells that need to be reset to "0".  Is this possible?  I don't want to clear the sheet because it will clear the drop down lists.

Below is what I have done already, but it won't save:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Wednesday').getSheetByName('Thursday').getSheetByName('Friday').getSheetByName('Saturday').getSheetByName('Monday').getSheetByName('Tuesday');
var resetselectrange ('B23', 'C4', 'G4', 'K4', 'O4', 'S4', 'A7:A16', 'E7:E16', 'I7:I16', 'M7:M16', 'Q7:Q16', 'A19:A23', 'E19:E23', 'I19:I23', 'M19:M23', 'Q19:Q23', 'A26:A29', 'E26:E29', 'I26:I29', 'M26:M29', 'Q26:Q29', 'A38:A41', 'E38:E41', 'I38:I41', 'M38:M41', 'Q38:Q41');
var resetzerorange ('C7:C16', 'G7:G16', 'K7:K16', 'O7:O16', 'S7:S16', 'C19:C23', 'G19:G23', 'K19:K23', 'O19:O23', 'S19:S23', 'C26:C29', 'G26:G29', 'K26:K29', 'O26:O29', 'S26:S29', 'C38:C41', 'G38:G41', 'K38:K41', 'O38:O41', 'S38:S41');
var clearrange ('F2', 'A32', 'E32', 'I32', 'M32', 'Q32');
```

I'm obviously not an expert at this, and apparently my logic is not the correct logic.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Wednesday').getSheetByName('Thursday').getSheetByName('Friday').getSheetByName('Saturday').getSheetByName('Monday').getSheetByName('Tuesday');
var resetselectrange ('B23', 'C4', 'G4', 'K4', 'O4', 'S4', 'A7:A16', 'E7:E16', 'I7:I16', 'M7:M16', 'Q7:Q16', 'A19:A23', 'E19:E23', 'I19:I23', 'M19:M23', 'Q19:Q23', 'A26:A29', 'E26:E29', 'I26:I29', 'M26:M29', 'Q26:Q29', 'A38:A41', 'E38:E41', 'I38:I41', 'M38:M41', 'Q38:Q41');
var resetzerorange ('C7:C16', 'G7:G16', 'K7:K16', 'O7:O16', 'S7:S16', 'C19:C23', 'G19:G23', 'K19:K23', 'O19:O23', 'S19:S23', 'C26:C29', 'G26:G29', 'K26:K29', 'O26:O29', 'S26:S29', 'C38:C41', 'G38:G41', 'K38:K41', 'O38:O41', 'S38:S41');
var clearrange ('F2', 'A32', 'E32', 'I32', 'M32', 'Q32');
```

The identified cells will be changed to "Select", Zero, or will clear entirely.

Comment: I realized that I forgot the "=" after the var resetxxx identifier and now I can save it.  I'm not sure what my next step is.

Comment: The code included doesn't make any sense. I think that you should take some steps back and learn the basics of JavaScript and Google Apps Script, like how `var` is used, how to declare and call functions.

Answer (score 1):

Several points:

- Please refer to [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) to consult the correct syntax of the methods you want to use
- The correct syntax for the methods in your questions are [getRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String)),[setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) and [clearRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear())
- To assign a range to a variable you need to use the `=` operator, as would be done in [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- To proceed several sheets simultaneously, use [loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) according to Javascript syntax.

Below is a sample code that will reset dropboxes in the specified ranges, I would like to encourage you to study the references provided to obtain a better understanding for Apps Script and Javascript (on which Apps Script is based) and being able to adapt this code to your needs as desired.

### Sample code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //designates sheets as an array that can contain multiple entries
  var sheets=[];
  //The following procedure could be simplified if you would like to select all sheets or e.g. the first 6 sheets of a spreadsheet
  sheets.push(ss.getSheetByName('Wednesday'));
  sheets.push(ss.getSheetByName('Thursday'));
  sheets.push(ss.getSheetByName('Friday'));
  sheets.push(ss.getSheetByName('Saturday'));
  sheets.push(ss.getSheetByName('Monday'));
  sheets.push(ss.getSheetByName('Tuesday'));
  for(var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    var resetselectrange=sheets[i].getRangeList(['B23', 'C4', 'G4', 'K4', 'O4', 'S4', 'A7:A16', 'E7:E16', 'I7:I16', 'M7:M16', 'Q7:Q16', 'A19:A23', 'E19:E23', 'I19:I23', 'M19:M23', 'Q19:Q23', 'A26:A29', 'E26:E29', 'I26:I29', 'M26:M29', 'Q26:Q29', 'A38:A41', 'E38:E41', 'I38:I41', 'M38:M41', 'Q38:Q41']).setValue(2);
    var resetzerorange=sheets[i].getRangeList(['C7:C16', 'G7:G16', 'K7:K16', 'O7:O16', 'S7:S16', 'C19:C23', 'G19:G23', 'K19:K23', 'O19:O23', 'S19:S23', 'C26:C29', 'G26:G29', 'K26:K29', 'O26:O29', 'S26:S29', 'C38:C41', 'G38:G41', 'K38:K41', 'O38:O41', 'S38:S41']).setValue('Select');
    var clearrange=sheets[i].getRangeList(['F2', 'A32', 'E32', 'I32', 'M32', 'Q32']).clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the assist!  This worked perfectly!  The problem is that we need the script to work on the iPhone app for Google Sheets.  It shows up in the app, but the buttons don't work.  Is there a way to get them to work in the iPhone app?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by buttons. Unfortunately I am not familiar with the iPhone app for Google Sheets.

Comment: The script above along with another are linked to a "button" in the Google sheet that will perform the functions in the script.  However, the script does not run in the iPhone app for Google Sheets when you tap on the "button" or double tap on it.  Thus the script is not working/usable in the iPhone app.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/add-a-script-trigger-to-google-sheet-that-will-work-in-android-mobile-app